# Choosing a data structure for calculating class schedule

Tags: java, graph, structure

I'm having trouble figuring out what kind of data structure to use. I'm trying to represent classes that need to be taken to complete a major, complete with prereqs. Originally, I was thinking of using and adjacency matrix to represent the data. However, I'm currently using an arraylist to store each course. Then, in each course object, I have an arraylist containing the parents of each course and the children of each course. I'm planning on having a dummy course with the first courses in its children array. Then I plan on doing a BFS and adding classes so long as the parents have been taken and the current course hasn't. I can't help but feeling that this isn't the ideal solution. I tried looking at the difference between lists, sets, and maps, and I can't come to a clear reason why one is superior to the other. All of the courses are unique and sets don't contain duplicates, so that seems to make sense. On the other hand, the order of classes taken matters, so a list seems like a good idea. Then again, I could have the course number be the key and the course object be the value in a map.

Comment: [Priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) is the data structure. The algorithm is called [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)

Comment: There's an awesome thing called Object-Oriented, you should totally check it out!

Comment: Yes, I have course objects for each course. I'm just trying to figure out how to choose a data structure to store all of these objects and correctly choose courses. Thank you for the suggestion though, alfasin. Smac, any guidance on how you ended up at a priority queue?

Comment: @mylasthope It can be done using a priority queue by setting a priority on which subject comes first before the other. But the actual arrangement of the subjects in such a way that subject k comes before subject k + 1 in the queue requires topological sorting algorithm

Comment: Thank you, Smac. I really appreciate the help. On a more general note, could you explain the thought process behind choosing the data structure and the algorithm or how I should go about doing so to arrive at the same conclusion? Based on all of the sites and books I've looked at describing the java collections classes, I was trying to look at the differences between the collections and how my problem fits into each collection. I'm having a hard time understanding when I should use a list instead of a set or when I should use a map instead of a list--and now a queue.